# What is the best practice for responsive website widths?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I have recently started learning how to use CSS media queries to develop websites that are responsive / mobile friendly however, I am not familiar with the best practices associated with determining which width ranges to develop designs for.

For example, I normally use three sets of CSS rules. One for a small width (mobile) , one for a medium width (tablet or small laptop screen) and one for a large width (desktop).

This is what it looks like in code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1495px)  {    
//CSS RULES HERE
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1494px) and (min-width: 1245px) {
//CSS RULES HERE
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1244px) and (min-width: 751px) {
//CSS RULES HERE
}
```

My sizing conventions (min width & max width) are completely arbitrary and I determine whether it works from trial and error. Often This doesn't work very well and I can't get the design to look good on all difference screen resolutions.

First of all.... Is there a best practice for the most ideal width ranges to use?

Secondly, is there a framework or template that will make all of this easier?

**(That is not Bootstrap).**

FYI: I use Foundation 6 to as a grid system but I haven't really found information much on responsive sites in Foundation 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems rare to me that you haven't found information about responsive sites on Foundation, this framework has been responsive from the beginning, and have wired cool stuff to help you on that matter. Just want to make clear I'm talking here about the **Float Grid** which isn't default anymore since 6.4 (but you can customize or switch up the grid in SASS settings).

Foundation grid has 3 default expected sizes: small (mobiles), medium (tablets) and large (desktop), in Float Grid you can use this way:

```
<div class="column small-12 medium-6 large-4></div>
```

This column will be full width on mobile, 1/2 width on tablet and 1/3 width on desktop; you can even ditch the `small-12` because every column has full width (12 columns) by default.

That's the way you approach it from the grid... if you use the SASS version of the framework, you have another powerful tool, a mixing to set code for a specific breakpoint... let's say you want to apply some styling for **medium** size (and up), you just need to use this in your `.scss` file:

```
@include breakpoint(medium) {
  // Your SASS/CSS code here
}
```

Please notice I said "medium and up", that's because Foundation is mobile-first, so everything you put in a smaller breakpoint, will be available on following sizes (unless you override them), if that philosophy is kinda awkward to you, and you need to put some code for *only the medium breakpoint*, you just need to put the code this way:

```
@include breakpoint(medium only) {
  // Your SASS/CSS code here
}
```

That's a quite fast way to handle mediaqueries inside your code, totally aligned with Foundation code... the best part?, if you change breakpoint sizes at mid-development, you just need to change the sizes on the `_settings.scss` file and all code will update on the next build.

As you tagged this question on "Foundation" and mentioned on the question body, I did my answer deliberately Foundation-centric. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a really helpful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually go for a single breakpoint at 768px. 
With that I go for three queries (and they worked out pretty well so far) :

- desktop (min-width is 768) [sheet #1]
- mobile (max-width is 768) [sheet #2]
- portrait (according to orientation) [sheet #2]

I don't think there's really a strict and fixed set of breakpoints that everyone should be using, I feel like it's more depending on what you need for your website.

Although, if you still wanna have a look at a set of breakpoints, I have bookmarked this a long time ago : [ResponsiveDesign.is - breakpoints](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to calculate the value of the font size in the HTML, then use a framework such as CSS to do the calculations dynamically